# Excel 2010 Macro to compare two columns for finding the matched value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am very new to Excel macros and VBA, kindly help me **please** with my below situation.
Here is the situation, i have two sheets (sheet1 and sheet 2) in sheet1 there is two columns name and number and in sheet2 i have numbers along its other information like date, charging and etc.

**Sheet 1**

No  Name        PhoneNumber

1    Bob          7254

2    Cristin      5468

3    Luara        1234

**Sheet2**

No  PhoneNumber    Date     Charged  Name

1   1145       12/30/2014     2$

2   7254       11/26/2014     3$

3   2365        3/9/2014      7$

4   5468        3/10/2014

5   1234        3/11/2014

What i want is to compare PhoneNumber column of sheet2 (B column) with PhoneNumber column of sheet1 (C column) and if a matching is found then copy Name (B column) from Sheet1 into Name column of sheet2 (E column). If no match then the name column in sheet2 must be blank.

i have searched and found the below code and modified a bit but i am not sure whether it is correct or no:

```
    Sub test()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
        For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i)
            For j = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j)
                If rng1.Value = rng2.Value Then
                    Range("B2:B" & TotalRows).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2")
                End If

            Set rng2 = Nothing
        Next j
        Set rng1 = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```

Please help me as the time is so short for my this project and i will highly appreciate your assistance in this regard.

Comment: Why dont you simply use VLOOKUP function for the same, it will be lot simpler in your case. Search on GOOGLE related to same.

Comment: Thanks Paresh for quick response,i know vlookup will be much easier but the requirement is using Macro :( if you have any idea i would appreciate your assistance!

Comment: You can use VLOOKUP function in your macro and then just fill the VLOOKUP formula for rest of the cells. You can use Application.VLOOKUP or Application.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you were almost there.  Your copy line needed a little tweaking, however.  In the example below, I added an additional variable called rngName, to store the range of the name to be copied and assigned it a value in the for j loop.  if the numbers match (i.e. rng1.value =  rng2.value) it will copy the range containing the name to the associated row in sheet 2.  Notice that I used .Range ("E" & i) for the copy-to range.  The copy-to range in your example would always drop the name in the same cell as its always assigned to "E2".  Also, you have a variable called TotalRows that had no value.  It must have meant something in the original code you copied it from, so I got rid of that too.  Try this and let me know how it works for you.

```
Sub test()
 Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngName As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i)
        For j = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j)
            Set rngName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & j)
            If rng1.Value = rng2.Value Then
                rngName.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i)
            End If

        Set rng2 = Nothing
    Next j
    Set rng1 = Nothing
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Edward for the help, it just need two correction the rest is working great.  Each loop should start from 2 value in order to prevent from headers' selection and we have to exit the second loop    once the rng1 & rng2 values are the same so the first loop could continue as below:                            If rng1.Value = rng2.Value Then
                rngName.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i)
         Exit For   End If