# Highlight changed results

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

I found this [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700515/excel-2010-macro-to-compare-two-columns-for-finding-the-matched-value/44617425#44617425) a few months ago and very useful. Thanks to [Edward Bagby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4404399/edward-bagby).

Now I want to know how to highlight the changed results? Not the text, but only the cell interior. Can someone help me?

I tried to add after `rngName.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i)`
some solutions like these:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = red
```

or

```
rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = red
```

but nothing to change.

**Thank You in advance!**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because '*Now I want to know how to highlight the changed results*' is **not** a specific programming problem and adding narrative debris like '*Thank You in advance!*' does nothing to change that.

Comment: I'm currently looking for a solution. But if I write something I can just mislead others. I can not write a possible solution.

Comment: Show in your original post what you have tried to modify the code to your needs and where you are stuck. Then ask a specific question about why it is not working.

Comment: Thank you for the correction proposal. Next time I will pay attention. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to change the **destination** range to have a red interior colour, you could use:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = vbRed
```

If you wish to change the **source** range to have a red interior colour, you could use:

```
rngName.Interior.Color = vbRed
```

Comment: If I changed the
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i)
to
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = vbRed
I got an error: Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Comment: @Donald - What do you mean by "changed"?  You said you had tried lines such as `ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = red` and `rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = red` but you didn't say you had tried `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = red`, so I am worried that you are changing your `Copy` command rather than using one of the lines I suggested instead of one of the lines you said you tried.