# Paste copied values with .PasteSpecial

Tags: vba, range, copy-paste

Please help me for this problem:

I use this vba from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700515/excel-2010-macro-to-compare-two-columns-for-finding-the-matched-value):

```
Sub test()
 Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngName As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i)
        For j = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j)
            Set rngName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & j)
            If rng1.Value = rng2.Value Then
                rngName.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i)
            End If

        Set rng2 = Nothing
    Next j
    Set rng1 = Nothing
 Next i
End Sub
```

Can somebody show me how to combine `rngName.Copy` with

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

I would like to earn, that the `rngName.Copy` copy only text, because I have special color, text format, comment etc. in the cells, where the vba paste the changed values and I would like to stay these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
rngName.Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, _
  Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

You may also want `xlPasteValues` instead of `xlPasteFormulas`. In this case, a simpler and better way is to take the value without using copy/paste:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i).Value = rngName.Value
```

All of the methods above conserve the formatting of the destination.

Comment: Wow. The second is easier, but great solution is both! Now I keep in mind, that need add to next row the xlPaste. Thank You A.S.H. I'm a beginner.